# Unreported IOException

Tags: java, json, jackson

Please help me. I am trying to read data from a json file and store them in java objects.Here is the code :

```
try {
    ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();

    File file2 = new File("Lessons.json");

    List<Lesson> lessonList = Arrays.asList(mapper2.readValue(file2, Lesson[].class));
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However it shows me the error:

```
Error   unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

in the line that I create the list of the objects.

Comment: The block of code that you posted doesn't appear capable of producing that error. Please [edit] your question to show a complete, compilable example of code that produces that error and the exact error that you're getting.

Comment: do u use spring?

Comment: no I am not ...

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your `try-catch` directly under class A. Please make sure that it is inside any method. Ideally, it should not show above error as `catch (Exception e)` block is already there. The below sample code is working fine to me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();
        File file2 = new File("Lessons.json");
        List<Lesson> lessonList = Arrays.asList(mapper2.readValue(file2, Lesson[].class));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```